# How to do looping and use case when logic from dynamicaly variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot

I'm new in mysql

Before I have question and have the answer from someone. But I need a improve again from the query.

This is my sampling data on mysql db

table test

[image: Sampling Data]

With this query on below from my Question before, i have result what i wanted.

```
select item, no_po, sum(qty) qty_total,
sum(case when child_customer='ha' then qty else 0 end) as customer_b_ha,
sum(case when child_customer='hi' then qty else 0 end) as customer_b_hi,
sum(case when child_customer='hu' then qty else 0 end) as customer_b_hu,
sum(case when child_customer='he' then qty else 0 end) as customer_b_he,
sum(case when child_customer='ho' then qty else 0 end) as customer_b_ho from test where received_date='2018-06-27'  group by item, no_po order by item asc
```

and this the result what i wanted.

[image: The Result]

My question is, How to do dynamically use single line only with child_customer variable parameter key (ha, hi, hu, he, ho) repeatedly up to "ho" from query below.

`sum(case when child_customer='ha' then qty else 0 end) as customer_b_ha,
    sum(case when child_customer='hi' then qty else 0 end) as customer_b_hi,
    sum(case when child_customer='hu' then qty else 0 end) as customer_b_hu,
    sum(case when child_customer='he' then qty else 0 end) as customer_b_he,
    sum(case when child_customer='ho' then qty else 0 end) as customer_b_ho`

note: Before, The Key ("ha","hi"."hu","he","ho") i've got from (SELECT distinct(child_customer) from test where received_date='2018-06-07')

Thank You,

Best Regard

Comment: There is no `pivot` in MySQL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your request you would like a different number of columns dependent on the number of distinct child_customer values. This is known as pivoting and the short answer is you can't in MySQL. One option is to loop over distinct child_customer and generate a query that you can execute. You can do this in a stored procedure or in your host language.

However, I suggest a query like:

```
select item, no_po, 'Total' as child_customer, sum(qty) qty
from test 
where received_date='2018-06-27'  
group by item, no_po
union all
select item, no_po, child_customer, sum(qty) qty
from test 
where received_date='2018-06-27'  
group by item, no_po, child_customer 
order by item asc, child_customer
```

and the do the pivoting in your application.

Comment: Hello mr lennart, Thank you. Yes, you're right, I want loop the by child_name as many members on it and by the name of child_name as a parameter clause. Thank you for your suggest. best regards.